# Select from table where there's multiple entries in one row

Tags: mysql, select, count, conditional-statements, having

I have some MySQL tables like those:

```
ids            urns             urn_urls     urls
id | type    id | uid | urn    uid | lid    lid | url
---+-----    ---+-----+-----   ----+----    ----+----
1  | 1        1 | 1   | urn1    1  |  1       1 | url1
2  | 4        2 | 2   | urn2    1  |  2       2 | url2      
3  | 4        2 | 3   | urn3    2  |  3       3 | url3
4  | 4        3 | 4   | urn4    2  |  4       4 | url4
...|...       3 | 5   | urn5    3  |  4       5 | url5
.             4 | 6   | urn6    4  |  5       6 | url6
.            ...| ... | ...     5  |  5      ...| ...
.                               6  |  1
.                               6  |  6
```

What i'd like to have is a query, which lists those id entries of type 4, which are related to more than one urn and the corrosponding urns, like this:

```
result
id | url
---+-----
2  | url3
2  | url4
4  | url1
4  | url6
```

i already tried something like this:

```
SELECT id,url 
  FROM ids 
  NATURAL JOIN urns 
  NATURAL JOIN urn_urls 
  NATURAL JOIN urls 
  WHERE type=4 
  HAVING count( #column# )>1;
```

with `#column#` one of (`id`, `lid`, `url`), but it only returns on row;
when i added a `GROUP BY` statement, i get more, but not apropriate results for

```
SELECT id,url 
  FROM ids 
  NATURAL JOIN urns 
  NATURAL JOIN urn_urls
  NATURAL JOIN urls 
  WHERE type=4 
  GROUP BY #group# 
  HAVING count( #column# )>1;
```

for different combinations of `#group#` / `#column#` out of (`id`, `lid`, `url`).

So, help is appreciated.

Comment: Why should `urn1` be in the result? It's connected to id 1, which has the type 1, not 4.

Comment: my fault. the result should contain the urls ;) i will edit this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about -

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(urls.url SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM ids 
NATURAL JOIN urns 
NATURAL JOIN urn_urls
NATURAL JOIN urls 
WHERE type=4 
GROUP BY ids.id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT urls.url)>1;
```

Comment: Almost what i want. This may work, if it is possible to concatenate by a space as separator (since a colon might also be part of an url). Even better woul be to have on result row per url as in my example.

Comment: You can use anything you like for the separator - [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Also, note that the length of the returned value is limited by `group_concat_max_len`

Comment: I tested this with my example, and noticed, that this will return the following:<br/>

`2 | url3 url4`<br/>
`3 | url5 url5`<br/>
`4 | url1 url6`<br/>

so, what i actually not wanted is id=3, since it is only related to one url (twice)

Comment: You can add DISTINCT to the COUNT -  `COUNT(DISTINCT urls.url)`

Comment: ok, so SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(urls.url SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM ids 
NATURAL JOIN urns 
NATURAL JOIN urn_urls
NATURAL JOIN urls 
WHERE type=4 
GROUP BY ids.id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT urls.url)>1; works!